# Java object to JSON with org.json lib

Tags: java, org.json

I have class like this:

```
public class Class1 {
    private String result;
    private String ip;
    private ArrayList<Class2> alarm;
}
```

Where Alarm its a class like this:

```
public class Class2 {
    private String bla;
    private String bla1;
}
```

Is there easy way to convert instance of Class1 to JSON object with org.json?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think the utilizing org.json.lib's [JSONObject(Object)](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-) constructor is what you're looking for.  It will construct a JSONObject from your Java Object based on its getters.  You can then use JSONObject#toString to get the actual Json produced.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(instanceOfClass1);
String myJson = jsonObject.toString();
```

Comment: His bean doesn't have any public accessor methods, therefore JSONObject won't be able to get ahold of his properties.

Comment: That's true.  I guess it may have been a poor assumption on my part that they were just left out for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo, your link is 404.

Answer (score 7):

While JSONObject is the way to go, you need to follow what its JavaDoc says about bean properties:

> Construct a JSONObject from an Object using bean getters. It reflects
>   on all of the public methods of the object. For each of the methods
>   with no parameters and a name starting with "get" or "is" followed by
>   an uppercase letter, the method is invoked, and a key and the value
>   returned from the getter method are put into the new JSONObject. The
>   key is formed by removing the "get" or "is" prefix. If the second
>   remaining character is not upper case, then the first character is
>   converted to lower case. For example, if an object has a method named
>   "getName", and if the result of calling object.getName() is "Larry
>   Fine", then the JSONObject will contain "name": "Larry Fine".

Based on the documentation, it will fail in your case because you don't expose those properties via gettings and setters.