# Read JSON file with JSONParser not available in the jarfile

Tags: java, json, readfile, jsonparser

I am trying to read a json file and convert it to the jsonObject and when I searched on how to do it, I came across the method to user

```
JSONParser parser= new JSONParse();
```

But the version of org.json I am using in the code is "**20180803**". It does not contain JSONParser. Has it been removed from the **org.json** package? If so what is the new class or method that I could use to read a json file and convert it to a json object.

My dependency is given below :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I would suggest explore Jackson library for Json processing

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use simple JSON.  You just need to add in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Sample code

```
public static JSONObject convertJsonStingToJson(String jsonString) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    return  json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`org.json` library has very simple `API` which does not have `JSONParser` but has `JSONTokener`. We can construct `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` directly from `String`:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // JSON Object
        String object = "{\"p1\":\"v1\", \"p2\":2}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(object);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        // JSON Array
        String array = "[{\"p1\":\"v1\", \"p2\":2}]";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(array);
        System.out.println(jsonArray);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"p1":"v1", "p2":2}
[{"p1":"v1","p2":2}]
```

You need to notice that it depends from `JSON` payload which class to use: if `JSON` starts from `{` use `JSONObject`, if from `[` - use `JSONArray`. In other case `JSON` payload is invalid.

As it mentioned in other answers, if you can you should definitely use [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) or [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is: **No, it was not removed, because it never existed**.

I think you are mentioning a library, and trying to use another one. Anyway, if you really want to use **org.json**, you can find how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7025761/5504607)

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(instanceOfClass1);
String myJson = jsonObject.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency in build file

```
//json processing
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8")
```

a.json file

```
{
  "a": "b"
}
```

code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("a.json");
        JsonNode obj =  objectMapper.readTree(input);
        System.out.println(obj.get("a")); // "b"
    }
}
```